# how can set a pointer to the content of a Mat variable in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

A Mat can be `CV_8UC3, CV_8UC1, CV_32FC3` and etc. For example, for a Mat which is `CV_8UC3`, I can set a pointer: `Vec3b *p` to the Mat. However, If I only know the Mat's datatype which can be obtained using `Mat.type()`, How can I set a proper pointer?

Answer (score 1):

The sad answer is: you can't. The type of data should be set in compilation time. But in your example actual type will be decided only during run time. You will have to put switch somewhere in your code. i.e. you will need to have different implementations of your algorithm for all possible types. Note however that you can prevent code duplication by using templates.

If you do know type of data, and the only thing you don't know is number of channels, then the problem is a bit simpler. For example if your image contains unsigned char you can write

```
uchar* p = img.ptr<uchar>();
```

And it doesn't matter whether your image have one channel or three. Of course when it comes to actually working with the pixels you do need this information.

Comment: the problem is that if the type is CV_32FC1, can we still use uchar*p? Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically, yes. If you use it in the same way I did. It will compile and run without crashing. It will even return you pointer to correct location in memory. But what can you do with it? Also note that if you will use .ptr() or .at() with any non-zero argument it will give you wrong locations.

Comment: I want to access each element in one Mat. Its type can be given using Mat::type(). But this can only know during the running time. I know that if I use your method, the code will run but the result will be wrong. For example, if the mat is CV_8UC3, but we use uchar*p, then the result will be mixed up.

Comment: In that case you will need different implementation for various numbers of channels (each implementation is template on data type)

Answer (score 0):

Use a void pointer.  Void pointers can point to any data type.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/

Comment: I don't understand this. For example, if I want to change the first element of a Mat(CV_8UC3), I set a void pointer to it. But we did not know how many bit an element should occupy. How can we cast the void pointer to a correct type? The only way I know is using switch to test all the datatype of Mat. But that should be not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a type, you can set a pointer to the first element of the first row of cv::Mat using `ptr` ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a13acd320291229615ef15f96ff1ff738))

```
cv::Mat matrix = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_32F);
float* firstElement = matrix.ptr<float>(0);
```